# OutOfMemoryError with Mallet CRF classifier

Tags: java, out-of-memory, mallet

The classifier frequently fails with OutOfMemoryError. Please suggest.

We have UIMA pipeline which invokes 5 model jars(based on mallet CRF) around 30MB each. -Xms is set to 2G and -Xmx is set to 4G.

Is there any guidelines/bench marking on setting the heap space?
Please point if there are any guidelines for multi threaded environment.

I did try applying the patch https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/issues/detail?id=408, this did not resolve the issue.

Heap dump shows that 42% of heap size is char[] and 15% is String.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at cc.mallet.types.IndexedSparseVector.setIndex2Location(IndexedSparseVector.java:109)
    at cc.mallet.types.IndexedSparseVector.dotProduct(IndexedSparseVector.java:157)
    at cc.mallet.fst.CRF$TransitionIterator.<init>(CRF.java:1856)
    at cc.mallet.fst.CRF$TransitionIterator.<init>(CRF.java:1835)
    at cc.mallet.fst.CRF$State.transitionIterator(CRF.java:1776)
    at cc.mallet.fst.MaxLatticeDefault.<init>(MaxLatticeDefault.java:252)
    at cc.mallet.fst.MaxLatticeDefault.<init>(MaxLatticeDefault.java:197)
    at cc.mallet.fst.MaxLatticeDefault$Factory.newMaxLattice(MaxLatticeDefault.java:494)
    at cc.mallet.fst.MaxLatticeFactory.newMaxLattice(MaxLatticeFactory.java:11)
    at cc.mallet.fst.Transducer.transduce(Transducer.java:124)
    at org.cleartk.ml.mallet.MalletCrfStringOutcomeClassifier.classify(MalletCrfStringOutcomeClassifier.java:90)
```

Model is created based on MalletCrfStringOutcomeDataWriter.

```
AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(DataChunkAnnotator.class,
        CleartkSequenceAnnotator.PARAM_IS_TRAINING, true, DirectoryDataWriterFactory.PARAM_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY,
        options.getModelsDirectory(), DefaultSequenceDataWriterFactory.PARAM_DATA_WRITER_CLASS_NAME, MalletCrfStringOutcomeDataWriter.class)
```

The annotator code looks as follows.

```
if (this.isTraining()) {
        List<DataAnnotation> namedEntityMentions = JCasUtil.selectCovered(jCas, DataAannotation.class, sentence);
        List<String> outcomes = this.chunking.createOutcomes(jCas, tokens, namedEntityMentions);
        this.dataWriter.write(Instances.toInstances(outcomes, featureLists));
      } else {
        List<String> outcomes = this.classifier.classify(featureLists);
        this.chunking.createChunks(jCas, tokens, outcomes);
      }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to:

1. increase Xmx
2. dive deeper into analyzing the heap: all strings are backed up by `char[]` - so knowing numbers like 42% and 15% is not helpful - you should investigate which part of your program allocates these strings.
3. Since it looks like the error is triggered in line: 
   `List<String> outcomes = this.classifier.classify(featureLists);` 
   you can start from there: try to figure out what's in `featureLists`, what's its size etc, and see what does the method `classify` do, and if you can "help" it become more efficient in term of memory. For example, reduce the use of `String` and replace it with `StringBuilder` and `append` (just an example).